# How to correctly override HashCode method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

> I define Class User and user has tow member varibles -> `NSString* name , NSSString* pass`
>   And I want to store them by `NSSet` Conllection so , I rewrite -(`NSUInteger`) hash method like following

```
-(NSUIntegar) hash
{
      NSLog(@"Hash Method  %@",[self class]);
      NSUInteger nameHash = name == nil ? 0 : [name hash];
      NSUInteger passHash = pass == nil ? 0 : [pass hash];
      return nameHash * 31 + passHash;
}
```

> **main.m** file

```
NSSet* set = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                  [[User alloc] initWithName:@"nike" pass:@"123"],
                  [[User alloc] initWithName:@"nool" pass:@"456"],
                  [[User alloc] initWithName:@"boow" pass:@"124"],
                  [[User alloc] initWithName:@"enla" pass:@"124"],
                  [[User alloc] initWithName:@"boow" pass:@"124"],//same as member 3
                  nil];
    NSLog(@"set count = %ld",[set count]);
    NSLog(@"%@",NSCollectionToString(set));
```

> NSCollectionToString(id collection)

```
NSString* NSCollectionToString(id collection)
{

NSMutableString* result = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:
                            @"["];
for (id object in collection) {
    [result appendString:[object description]];
    [result appendString:@","];
}
NSUInteger len = [result length];

[result deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(len - 1, 1)];
[result appendString:@"]"];
return result;
}
```

> But console output :   set count = 5 
>   Why not 4 ?  where mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override *both* the hash function and the isEqual: method.

The hash function must return the same hash value for any two objects that are equal according to isEqual. It *should* return different values for objects that are not equal according to isEqual, but that isn't essential except for performance. The default isEqual function just compares the object pointers, so two objects with the same data compare not equal. That's why your two objects with equal data were both added to the set.